# Show value within bar on flot bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I would like to show the value within the bar on the [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) bar chart, something like this:

```
|
|               +----+
|               |    |
|               |    |
|               |    |
|   +----+      | 20 |
|   |    |      |    |
|   | 10 |      |    |
|   |    |      |    |
|---+----+------+----+------
```

data = [[1, 10], [2, 20]]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 16):

I needed the same thing, so I quickly hacked together a [plugin](https://github.com/joetsoi/flot-barnumbers) for it and a quick [example](http://joetsoi.github.com/flot-barnumbers/) of it in action.

Comment: Mine is pretty buggy. I guess it because my flot is display the bars horizontal. http://www21.speedyshare.com/nGkvr/download/barnum.jpg . Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: yeah, you're right, I've fixed it to take into account the horizontal bars.

Comment: @dinosaurwaltz i get an error when i tried using this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null at formatter (jquery.flot.barnumbers.js:60)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.flot.barnumbers.js:121)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.3.js:384)
    at draw (jquery.flot.barnumbers.js:57)
    at executeHooks (jquery.flot.js:717)
    at draw (jquery.flot.js:1886)
    at new Plot (jquery.flot.js:710)
    at Function.$.plot (jquery.flot.js:3146)
    at plot_graph (graphs.php:975)
    at Object.success (graphs.php:683)`

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is here:

http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=218

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not exactly what I was looking for. this plugin shows the value on top of the bar, i would like to show it **in** the bar.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [flot.barlabels](https://github.com/cleroux/flot.barlabels) can be used:

[image]