# Show value within the bar - jQuery plot horizontal stacked bar chart

Tags: jquery, charts, flot, stacked

I would like to show the value within the bar on the flot bar chart (horizontal and stacked), something like this :

```
|-------------------------------------------
|                 5                 |   1  |
|-------------------------------------------
|
|------------------------------------
|           3         |       2     |
|------------------------------------
```

I saw this post : [Show value within bar on flot bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892160/show-value-within-bar-on-flot-bar-chart)
The values appears only inside the first stacked bar. The second value is the current total, not the corresponding value of the current bar, eg :

```
|-------------------------------------------
|                 5  6               |     |
|-------------------------------------------
|
|------------------------------------
|           3 5        |            |
|------------------------------------
```

Do someone know a good plugin for this functionality?
Also, I would like to increase the font size inside the bar.

Thank you!

---

Here the code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.barnumbers.js"></script>

var data = [
        {label: 'Label 1', color:"#80FF80", data: [[1,5], [2,3]]},
        {label: 'Label 2', color:"#FF8080", data: [[1,1], [2,2]]}
];

//reverse data for horizontal
for (series in data){
    var s = data[series];
    for (i=0;i<s.data.length;i++){
            var tmp = s.data[i][0];
        s.data[i][0] = s.data[i][1];
        s.data[i][1] = tmp;        
    }
}

var options = {
    series: {
        stack: 0,
        lines: {show: false, steps: false },
        bars: {
            show: true, 
            barWidth: 0.5, 
            align: 'center', 
            horizontal: true, 
            showNumbers: true
        },
    },
    yaxis: {ticks: [[1,'Category 1'], [2,'Category 2']]},
};

$.plot($("#flot-example-2"), data, options);
```

Comment: Can you post your code? http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Sorry, I just added the code, thank you !

Comment: You can see the demo here : http://codepen.io/anon/full/mrbdK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated flot-barnumbers to support stacked bars, see the updated [examples](http://joetsoi.github.com/flot-barnumbers/). If you need any other features, shoot me an email or open an issue, I only saw this question by chance.

Comment: 1st question: how can I format the numbers? 2nd question: how can I show these values just on mouse hover? Thanks. @dinosaurwaltz

Answer (score 1):

It seems that flot-barnumbers doesn't support stacked bar chart. That's why value labeled improperly. I'd recommend to use jqBarGraph, which is jQuery plugin to implement stacked bar charts.

http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/

I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to use [Highcharts Plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/) because it is much better documented and it works well!