# Flot Data Labels on Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

```
Too much code to paste here so....
```

Please see JS Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/1a2s35m2/ for current code.

I am attempting to create a horizontal bar chart using flot. As you will see from the Fiddle, this works fine but I want to display the values of the bars within the bars themselves and not as labels in the Y Axis, as in the picture below...
[image]

I have attempted to use the "labels" plugin and also the barnumbers plugin but these don't seem to work. (Barnumbers comes close but displays 0 1 2 3 as the values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892160/show-value-within-bar-on-flot-bar-chart).

Here is a good [example](http://joetsoi.github.io/flot-barnumbers/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm really starting to sound like a [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701504/jquery-flot-valuelabels-center/21708772#21708772) [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757085/how-to-add-labels-in-jquery-flot-chart/21761962#21761962) on here, but as your charts become really complicated forget the plugins and do it yourself.

Here's modified code from my links above catered for how you drew your plots:

```
    // after initial plot draw, then loop the data, add the labels
    // I'm drawing these directly on the canvas, NO HTML DIVS!
    // code is un-necessarily verbose for demonstration purposes
    var ctx = somePlot.getCanvas().getContext("2d"); // get the context
    var allSeries = somePlot.getData();  // get your series data
    var xaxis = somePlot.getXAxes()[0]; // xAxis
    var yaxis = somePlot.getYAxes()[0]; // yAxis
    var offset = somePlot.getPlotOffset(); // plots offset
    ctx.font = "12px 'Segoe UI'"; // set a pretty label font
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    for (var i = 0; i < allSeries.length; i++){
        var series = allSeries[i];        
        var dataPoint = series.datapoints.points; // one point per series
        var x = dataPoint[0];
        var y = dataPoint[1];  
        var text = x + '%';
        var metrics = ctx.measureText(text);        
        var xPos = xaxis.p2c(x)+offset.left - metrics.width; // place at end of bar
        var yPos = yaxis.p2c(y) + offset.top - 2;
        ctx.fillText(text, xPos, yPos);
    }
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1a2s35m2/1/).